# why after some stages, all the taskes are assigned to one machine(excuter) in spark?

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark

I encountered this problem: when i run a machine learning task on spark, after some stages, all the taskes are assigned to one machine(excutor), and the stage execution get slower and slower.

**[the spark conf setting]**

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(sparkMaster).setAppName("ModelTraining").setSparkHome(sparkHome).setJars(List(jarFile))
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
conf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "LRRegistrator")
conf.set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.7")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
conf.set("spark.cores.max", "150")
conf.set("spark.speculation", "true")
conf.set("spark.storage.blockManagerHeartBeatMs", "300000")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://xxx:52310"+inputPath , 3)
val trainset = lines.map(parseWeightedPoint).repartition(50).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
```

**[the warn log from the spark]**

```
14/09/19 10:26:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to fetch failure from BlockManagerId(45, TS-BH109, 48384, 0)
14/09/19 10:27:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 726 (task 14.0:9)
14/09/19 10:29:03 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Ignored task status update (737 state FAILED) from unknown executor Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@TS-BH96:33178/user/Executor#-913985102] with ID 39
14/09/19 10:29:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to fetch failure from BlockManagerId(30, TS-BH136, 28518, 0)
14/09/19 11:01:22 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(47, TS-BH136, 31644, 0) with no recent heart beats: 47765ms exceeds 45000ms
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the executor log -- anything suspect there? In particular, you have Lost TID 726 (task 14.0:9). Further up in the driver log you should see which executor TID 726 was assigned to -- I'd check the error log on that machine and see if anything of interest shows up there.

My guess (and it's only a guess) is that your executor is crashing. At which point the system will try to launch a new executor but that is generally slow. In the mean time the current task might get resent to an existing executor hosing your system further.